how to insert image using interactive frid and display it in interactive grid in oracle apex?
I have interactive grid page .
I want to insert employee data that include his image.In addition to display this image with the data.
I tried to do that using (sys.dbms_lob.getlength("EMP_PHOTO")"EMP_PHOTO" )but i get number in the interactive grid column.
I also insert the photo from form because the field photo in interactive gride has no type of upload file
is there any way to do that?

Currently, there is no support for displaying images or handling blobs. I recommend using a separate form to upload and display the image. Try with a column as link and point the link to that separate page form

the page form can't display image. Is there any way to display the image in the form page?

Yes, a form yes can display an image. Use display image item and use a select to get the data
